# Chaining together Monos where functions return result codes not complete object

Tags: java, project-reactor

With a starting point of a `Mono<Person>` I would like to be able to call several functions to perform operations on it. These functions take the `Mono<Person>` and will return `Mono<String>` or `Mono<Integer>` i.e. perhaps the ID of the entry in the database and the result of a REST call.

What I am struggling with is how to chain the calls together such that I can get back to the `Mono<Person>` to make the second (and any future) calls.

The code below works but I would like to know if there is a better pattern using a different Mono function which removes the need for the intermediate map() calls.

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String getName() { return this.name; }
    private void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    static Mono<Person> p = Mono.just(new Person("Bob", 42));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Want to call doThing1() first, once that 
        // returns perform doThing2()
        Mono<Person> personMono = p.flatMap(person -> doThing1(person)
                .map(s -> person))
        .flatMap(person -> doThing2(person)
                .map(i -> person));
        personMono.subscribe();
    }

    // i.e. store in DB and return ID string
    private static Mono<String> doThing1(Person person) {
        return Mono.just("12345");
    }

    // i.e. perform some operation i.e. REST 
    // call and return status code
    private static Mono<Integer> doThing2(Person person) {
        return Mono.just(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` or `flatMap()` functions that perform side effects are usually a code smell in any case, and *definitely* a code smell if you're only using them for that purpose and ignoring the result (as you seem to be doing here.) They should only be used to transform, or map each element of the stream into another.

Instead, if you want something to *consume* the value on the stream and do something with it (ie. perform a side effect whenever an element is emitted), use `doOnNext()`:

```
Mono<Person> personMono = p
        .doOnNext(Person::doThing1)
        .doOnNext(Person::doThing2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `map` you can use [`thenReturn`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#thenReturn-V-) operator which is a bit more readable and expressive.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mono<Person> personMono = p.flatMap(person -> doThing1(person).thenReturn(person))
                               .flatMap(person -> doThing2(person).thenReturn(person));
    personMono.subscribe();
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any operator that would do this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this and which one to use depends on exactly what behavior you want to achieve.

`doThing1` and `doThing2` both return `Mono`s so they probably do something asynchronous in your real scenario.

If `doThing2`'s Mono should only be subscribed to once `doThing1`'s `Mono` completes, you can do this:

```java
p.flatMap(person -> doThing1(person)
                      .then(doThing2(person))
```

If both should be executed concurrently, but the `personMono` should only be completed when both `doThing1` and `doThing2` are completed, you can use `and` instead of `then`:

```java
p.flatMap(person -> doThing1(person)
                      .and(doThing2(person))
```

If it doesn't matter when `doThing1` and `doThing2` are finished, you could do something similar to Michael Berry's answer:

```java
p.doOnNext(person->doThing1(person).subscribe())
  .doOnNext(person->doThing2(person).subscribe())
```

Note that you will usually need to subscribe to the `Mono`s for any asynchronous processing to start.